# Visual Studio Code - Task.Todo Exstension

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have installed [Extension Todo+](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-todo-plus) in VSC Version 1.60.2 - OS Kali Linux. I will show with images the issue I have. A few years ago I have fix that problem using shortcuts on the keyboards but I forgot them now. The screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot]

Note: This problem can be fixed with shortcuts on the keyboard. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your settings.json via `CMD/CTRL + SHIFT + P`
- Type `Open Settings (JSON)`, and go into it
- Add `"editor.wordWrap": "on"` then save